# Spark submit with oozie

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I have written a spark code -

```
customDF.registerTempTable("customTable")
var query = "select date, id ts,errorode from customTable"
val finalCustomDF = hiveContext.sql(query)     
finalCustomDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/user/oozie/data")
```

When i run this code using spark submit, it runs fine but when i run it using oozie coordinator. I get following exception.

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: character '<EOF>' not supported here; line 1 pos 111
```

I have tried reading data from existing hive table it works but issue is with customTable.

Comment: AnalysisException Thrown when a query fails to analyze, usually because the query itself is invalid.First you should make sure spark can read the table normally.Second,var query = "select date, id,timestamp,errorode from customTable" I think.

Comment: Side comment: `timestamp` is a reserved word in SQL so it's very unwise to use it as a column name or column alias; also, I systematically use the `as` keyword to define column aliases, just because it's easier to read (cf. comment above...) -- but that's probably not what is causing that error message.

Comment: @Wang I am registering temp table above and trying to use that

Comment: looks like you are missing a comma between id and ts. Have you tried adding that in and seeing if it worked?